# Linux logrotation file showing incorrect size than usual

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have enabled logrotation under springboot directory and it is working but what i see is, "content-data-svc.log" is actually 2MB but when i do ls -ltrh it is showing as 61MB.

if i view the log file, there are more empty lines in the log file and thus creating file size to be large. 50% of the log file is with empty space and rest are log entries. Any idea why this is occurring?

```
[aemelics@springboot]$ ls -ltrh
total 4.6M
-rw------- 1 aemelics aemelics 1.6M Apr 11 06:44 content-data-svc.log.2.gz
-rw------- 1 aemelics aemelics 1.1M Apr 12 00:44 content-data-svc.log.1.gz
-rw------- 1 aemelics aemelics  61M Apr 12 02:00 content-data-svc.log
[aemelics@springboot]$ du -shx content-data-svc.log
2.0M    content-data-svc.log
```

Below is my logrotate entries:

[aemelics@springboot]$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/react

```
/logs/springboot/*.log*
{
su aemelics aemelics
    missingok
    daily
    minsize 20M
    copytruncate
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    compress
    rotate 5
    postrotate
    endscript
}
```

Comment: (Probably) unrelated comment: The pattern should be `/logs/springboot/*.log` (no `*` at the end), or `logrotate` will try to rotate the already rotated log files.

Comment: Do you know if the program writing to this log file has opened the file for _appending_ to? If it hasn't, and the logfile is truncated, it would create a "hole" at the start of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, the program keeps on writing the logs into the content-data-svc.log for every second. Will this cause an conflict?

Comment: if i vi the file - 60% of the file is occupied with                               
 [root@wsvmlncdp02 11]# vi content-data-svc.log.1
 ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the file looks large in the output of `ls` but small in the output of `du`, and that there appears to be empty space at the start of the file after rotation is that whatever program is writing to the log file is *not* opening the file for "appending" to.

When the log file is rotated, with the `copytruncate` option set in the `logrotate` configuration file, a copy of the file is created and the original file is *truncated*.  When a file is truncated, it's contents is effectively deleted, but the file itself is not deleted.

Ordinarily, a program would have opened the file for appending to.  This means that each new write to the log happens at the *end* of the file, always.  When the file is truncated, this means that the next log line would be written at the start of the file, because that's also where the end is at that point.

However, if the program *hasn't* opened the file in append mode, the next write will go to whatever offset into the file the last write finished at, regardless of whether the file was truncated or not.

If the file has been truncated by `logrotate`, this means that the write creates a hole in the file between the start and the point where the write happens. This hole is full of null bytes, which the `vi` editor shows as `^@`.

This is what happens in your case.

A file with such a hole is called a "sparse" file.  The null bytes in the hole itself are not actually stored on disk, which is why `du` shows a quite small size, but if you read the file from start to finish, you would read 61M of data (the logical size of the file, which is what `ls` shows).

To solve this, either

1. rewrite the program that writes to the log file so that it opens the file in append mode, or
2. tell the program to *reopen* the log file when the file is rotated (this is usually done by sending the program a `HUP` signal from `logrotate`, but you should read your program's manual), or
3. restart the program from `logrotate` when the log is rotated.