# Why am I still seeing old log files and not having new ones?

Tags: linux, command-line, logs, logrotate, delete

This is my setting logrotate

```
 /home/sy/logs/kitxit*/*/tend.log
    {
        daily
        rotate 10
        dateext
        compress
        delaycompress
        copytruncate
        missingok
        notifempty
        su apache apache
    }
```

Output is like below

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache     4096 Apr 30 13:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 apache apache     4096 Apr 30 13:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 21318609 May  2 21:25 tend.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache     4091 Feb 24 03:02 tend.log-20200224.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache     4065 Feb 25 03:02 tend.log-20200225.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache     4460 Feb 26 03:03 tend.log-20200226.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache     4049 Feb 27 03:03 tend.log-20200227.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache     2619 Feb 28 03:03 tend.log-20200228.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache     1312 Feb 29 03:03 tend.log-20200229.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache     1339 Mar  1 03:03 tend.log-20200301.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache     1305 Mar  2 03:03 tend.log-20200302.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache     2669 Mar  3 03:02 tend.log-20200303.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache    70011 Mar  4 03:03 tend.log-20200304
```

Why am I still seeing old log files and not having new ones?

This is a result of debug mode

```
 [root@xavs-ken logrotate.d]# logrotate -dv kitxit-tend-sylog
reading config file kitxit-tend-sylog
Allocating hash table for state file, size 15360 B

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /home/sy/logs/kitxit*/*/tend/*.log
/home/sy/logs/kitxit*/*/sylog/*.log
 after 1 days (10 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 48 and egid to 48
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit2/bola/tend/sql.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit2/bola/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/bola/tend/mem.log
  log does not need rotating (log is empty)considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/bola/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/clpl/tend/sql.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/clpl/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/mol/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/pola/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/solsa/tend/sql.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/solsa/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/sario/tend/mem.log
  log does not need rotating (log is empty)considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/sario/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/sasu/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/kilo/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/mixi/tend/mem.log
  log does not need rotating (log is empty)considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/mixi/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/aziz/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/xondana/tend/tend.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit2/bola/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/bola/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/clpl/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/mol/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/pola/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/solsa/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/entag/sylog/action.log
  log does not need rotating (log is empty)considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/sario/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/sasu/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/kilo/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/mixi/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/aziz/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/xondana/sylog/action.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /home/sy/logs/kitxit2/bola/tend/sql.log, log->rotateCount is 10
dateext suffix '-20200503'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding logs to compress failed
copying /home/sy/logs/kitxit2/bola/tend/sql.log to /home/sy/logs/kitxit2/bola/tend/sql.log-20200503
truncating /home/sy/logs/kitxit2/bola/tend/sql.log
rotating log /home/sy/logs/kitxit2/bola/tend/tend.log, log->rotateCount is 10
dateext suffix '-20200503'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding logs to compress failed
glob finding old rotated logs failed
```

...

Comment: `man logrotate` offers a debug option, which "_means that no changes are made to the logs and [...] debug messages are printed_". Have you tried it?

Comment: @roaima, thanks for reply. I have edited result of debug mode, it seems that it not rotating properly.

Comment: You may have to make the application reopen the log file upon rotation (often done by sending a `HUP` signal to the process). If it hasn't opened the log in append mode, it would otherwise just write to the same point in the file.  Is the `tend.log` file filled with null bytes in the beginning of the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579528/linux-logrotation-file-showing-incorrect-size-than-usual

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't think so - if you look at the dates of the older rotated files you'll see that rotation has just stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log files in the debug output do not correspond to the logrotate path in the configuration file.

Files matching `tend.log` in the debug output

```
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit2/bola/tend/tend.log
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/clpl/tend/tend.log
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/mol/tend/tend.log
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/pola/tend/tend.log
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/solsa/tend/tend.log
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/sasu/tend/tend.log
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/kilo/tend/tend.log
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/aziz/tend/tend.log
considering log /home/sy/logs/kitxit/xondana/tend/tend.log
```

Logrotate configuration

```
/home/sy/logs/kitxit*/*/tend.log
```

This pattern would need to be amended as follows to match the files being considered, i.e. with another `*/` in the path

```
/home/sy/logs/kitxit*/*/*/tend.log
```

Since your target files are being referenced in the debug output I would surmise that there is another logrotate snippet somewhere that stopped working around March 4th/5th.

Comment: thank you, I`ll give a try

Comment: @janobX I'm curious, what was actually wrong?